# Unrolling loop more than loop limits

Tags: c++

I never tried loop unrolling before. Please bare with my silly doubt.

I tried following and it works as it should.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;
int main(){
  #pragma unroll 4
for(int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
    cout<<"Hi"<<endl;
  getch();
return 0;
}
```

This spawns 4 threads to do the task and print Hi 4 times. Then I tried following code and it printed Hi 3 times as it should.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;
int main(){
  #pragma unroll 4
for(int i=0 ; i<3 ; i++)
    cout<<"Hi"<<endl;
  getch();
return 0;
}
```

Now my question is:

What if I try to unroll loop more than loop limits ? In this case will there be 4 threads out of which 3 will do useful work and 1 will wait for others to finish or compiler will auto-correct it and only 3 threads will be spanned ? I hope I was clear with my naive question. Pardon my ignorance. I am learning. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Loop unrolling has nothing to do with multi-threading. Are you by any chance confusing the two?

Comment: Won't #pragma turn this section into 4 Posix threads , each doing one iteration ? I want to understand what #pragma does behind the scenes in this case.

Comment: Is this CUDA by any chance? The only thing I find where `#pragma unroll` is valid is CUDA. In that case, I know little about it so you can disregard my comment.

Comment: I was going to use it in CUDA eventually. I am using visual studio and have CUDA installed. Hence it worked for simple c++ program also :). I would appreciate any info Mysticial. Thanks.

Comment: If this is CUDA, you should tag it as such. The C++ people probably won't have answers for you, because this isn't C++.

Comment: Done . Sorry for confusion Sophit.

Comment: It's not CUDA either.  This is entirely host (CPU) code.  And there are [other compilers besides CUDA](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp7a.doc%2Fcompiler%2Fref%2Frnpgunrl.htm) which recognize `#pragma unroll`.  The reason this code prints `"Hi"` 4 times is because you have a loop that iterates 4 times.  There are no threads being spawned or anything like that.  It has nothing to do with the unroll directive, which is likely being completely ignored by any host compiler you are likely using.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you [read the documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#pragma-unroll).

In CUDA, the unroll directive only applies to device code loops.  The statements made in the question about what is happening regarding threads are not correct.  In fact, an unrecognized `pragma` placed in C/C++ code should have no effect on the code at all, and your results bear that out.

> What if I try to unroll loop more than loop limits ?

From the documentation:

> The compiler will also insert code to ensure correctness ... It is up to the programmer to make sure that the specified unroll number gives the best performance.

Using `#pragma  unroll` should never generate "broken" code by itself.  If you do something crazy (like unroll a loop 100 times that will never be executed more than a few times in practice) then you're likely to get less performant results than just leaving it up to the compiler to handle.

In most cases, I would suggest not using this directive unless you understand the general optimization principle of [loop unrolling](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2001/cmsc411/proj01/proja/loop.html) and are also comfortable with inspecting loops at assembly (SASS) level.   Alternatively, if you have fixed-trip-length loops, some trial and error along with benchmarking may lead to useful results without resorting to careful analysis.  Casual usage of this directive is not likely to produce code that will run faster than what the compiler generates.  From the documentation:

> By default, the compiler unrolls small loops with a known trip count.

Comment: Thanks you so much ! I just got confused because I saw output with #pragma so I thought I have a thread per iteration. I think what you said makes sense : My compiler ignored it and executed it just like a normal code.